# Add dynamically signers for bulk signing

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on creating a gateway using the docusign API.
And i wonder if it's possible to add dynamically signers through a form.

I have tried many technique but none of them have worked.

For me one of the solution would be to add the signers with their parameters to a list in the model and use this list as a parameter of the controller, but i don't know if the Api have special limitation.

I will share you my code if you need it !

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do [bulk send](https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/features/bulk-send), but not sure.
Bulk Send is a feature where you send the same envelope (set of documents with tags etc.) to different signers (recipients). You then set the list and the system clones the original envelope many times and sends it to each user in turn.
Code example showcasing how to do this in 8 different languages can be found here:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/bulk-send-envelopes

Comment: Hi Inbar Gazit, thank you for your fast response. I already have read all the Docusign docs about Bulk sending (also the e-mail sending one) and done many test on the API. My real question is now to know if it's possible to add dynamically through a form as much signers (recipient) as i want?  I can share you already what i have done.

Comment: sure, I think you should ask a new question and mark this as answered. If you share your code here - it would be easier to reply.